# Unable to pay more than $10,000 through stripe

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, magento2

Stripe throwing the following error on above $10,000 payments for the address California, 94954

Amount for an export transaction must be less than $10,000

The project setup is magento 2, Is there any magento configurations needed specially for this?

Comment: You should reach out to Stripe support for this: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: @PaulAsjes Is there any possibility to increase the limit?

Comment: You'll have to talk to Stripe support about that.

Answer (score 0):

Indian merchants that accept international payments on Stripe are limited to a maximum of $10000 USD per payment. This is a regulatory limit documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments